# Find largest integer from objects within array and return a key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I'm trying to write a function that takes as a parameter an array of objects, like this: 
`function getOldest([{name:john, age:69}, {name:jane, age:28}, {name:paul, age: 19}])`

The function would check the age property of the objects and find the largest value, and then return the name property.

```
getOldest([{name: john, age: 35}, {name: jane, age: 20}, {...}])
returns "john"
```

Additionally, if two key value pairs share the same value, as in two people have the same age, it would return an array instead.

```
getOldest([{name: john, age: 20}, {name: jane, age: 20}, {...}])
returns ['john', 'jane']
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for about five hours now but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: So tell us, how does your function `getOldest()` look...

Comment: `trying to write a function` - so far you've written the name of a function ... keep trying

Comment: Sort the array in desc order get the first element.

Comment: @JaromandaX funny. I tried looping through the array using a for loop selecting the values of age with person[i].age and then an if statement that would go through the values, adding the largest one to an empty variable but that didn't work since I couldn't link that back to the object. Took me a few tries with different versions before I realized I don't know enough to write the code I want.

Comment: the answer is tow use array reduce - this should be as much of an answer as you get, as you've shown zero effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sort`, then `filter` and finally `map`

```
var arr = [{name:"john", age:69}, {name:"jane", age:28}, {name:"paul", age: 19}];
arr.sort( ( a, b ) => b.age - b.age ); //sort by age in reverse
var maxAge = arr[ 0 ].age; //find max age
var output  = arr.filter( a => a.age == maxAge ).map( a => a.name ); //returns array of max age name
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "john",
  age: 69
}, {
  name: "jane",
  age: 28
}, {
  name: "paul",
  age: 19
}];
arr.sort((a, b) => b.age - b.age); //sort by age in reverse
var maxAge = arr[0].age; //find max age
var output = arr.filter(a => a.age == maxAge).map(a => a.name); //returns array of max age name
console.log(output);
```

Or **find the `maxAge` first** using `map`

```
var arr = [{name:"john", age:69}, {name:"jane", age:28}, {name:"paul", age: 19}];
var maxAge = Math.max.apply( null, arr.map( a => a.age ) );
var output  = arr.filter( a => a.age == maxAge ).map( a => a.name ); //returns array of max age name
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{name:"john", age:69}, {name:"jane", age:28}, {name:"paul", age: 19}];
var maxAge = Math.max.apply( null, arr.map( a => a.age ) );
var output  = arr.filter( a => a.age == maxAge ).map( a => a.name ); //returns array of max age name
console.log( output );
```

Comment: *sort* affects the original array. One *reduce* is sufficient.

Comment: @RobG Added another method

Answer (score 1):

I would always return an array to keep consistency:

```
 function getOldest(arr){
   const old = arr.reduce((acc, {age}) => Math.max(acc, age), 0);
   return arr.filter(({age}) => age === old);
 }
```

At first it goes through the array with reduce and finds the oldest age, then it returns the array filtered by that.

---

If you want to reduce in one step:

```
 function getOldest(arr){
   var old = 0;
   return arr.reduce((arr, {name, age}) => {
     if(age > old){
       old = age;
       return [name];
     }
     if(age === old) return arr.concat(name);
     return arr;
  }, []);
 }
```

Comment: Why not post it here as a runnable snippet? You shouldn't need *filter*, just make the accumulator from the appropriate names.

Comment: @robG cause the `<>` button is disabled on mobile devices ;/

Comment: You're keen… I don't bother on my iPhone 5. ;-)

Comment: @robg added reducing in one step however thats slightly more convoluted on my opinoon ;)

Comment: @JonasW Try with `getOldest(  [{name:"john", age:69}, {name:"jane", age:28}, {name:"paul", age: 19}] )`

Comment: @gurvinder thanks for pointing out, [fixed it ;)](http://jsbin.com/xupelejuka/edit?console)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getOldest(arr){

    return arr.reduce( function(acc,current){
       if (acc.age > current.age) {
          return acc
       } else { return current}
    }).name

 }
```

Edit: **It's actually the best method here, just a reduce and that's it, no sorting or filtering.**

Comment: This just returns the first object with the max age, not what the OP wants. If it was the correct result, consider the simpler: `return acc.age > current.age? acc : current`, ;-)

Comment: No it's not! Next time just check my answer in a compiler.

Comment: You could have posted it here as a runnable snippet. It doesn't accommodate duplicates, so not what the OP wants. It will also throw an error if *arr* is empty as you haven't provided an initial accumulator.

Comment: Rob, just be more attentive next time.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are answers already… it seems to me *reduce* is sufficient. Also, I think it's better to always return an array. Functions that return different types depending on some random criterion aren't friendly:

```js
function getOldest(data) {
  var max = -Infinity;
  return data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    obj.age > max? (acc = [obj.name]) && (max = obj.age) :
    obj.age == max? acc.push(obj.name): null;
    return acc;
  },[]);
}

var data = [{name: 'paul', age: 19}, 
            {name: 'john', age: 69},
            {name: 'jane', age: 28},
            {name: 'fred', age: 13},
            {name: 'tom' , age: 69}];

console.log(getOldest(data));
```

Comment: Why the boolean algebra if you are returning afterwards?

Comment: @JonasW.—because it's shorter than if..else and means there's only one return (since the callback needs to return the accumulator). I'm open to a better way.

Comment: `(acc, obj) => obj.age > max && (max = age) && [obj.name] || obj.age === max && acc.concat(obj) || acc`

Comment: @JonasW.—that has errors, doesn't return what the OP wants or in the correct format. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
var myarray = [{name: 'john', age: 35}, {name: 'jane', age: 20}];
var oldest = getoldest(myarray);
alert(oldest.name);
```

and in the function you could do something like this

```
function getoldest(myarray){
 var oldest = Math.max.apply(Math,myarray.map(function(myarray){return myarray.age;}));
 var obj = myarray.find(function(o){return o.age == oldest;});
 return obj;
};
```

This way you could use the returned object for something else.